# What is number of 'command' operations reported by mongostat?

Tags: mongodb

I am monitoring my database performance using the mongostat tool. The tool is reporting data every second. The output shows the following data

```
insert query update delete getmore command
  2063  3101   2062   1027       0  4131|0
  2103  3192   2105   1056       0  4239|0
```

The mongostat documentation says, commands:

```
command
  The number of commands per second. On secondary systems, mongostat 
  presents two values separated by a pipe character (e.g. |), in the form of
  local|replicated commands.
```

From MongoDb point of view, what is a 'command' which it executes at ~4000 operations per second? I am not running any other administrative, diagnostics, session, or sharding commands on the MongoDb instance.

Is 'command' counter tell the cumulative number of aggregate, count, or group operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> opcounters.command counts all commands except the write commands: insert, update, and delete

From the docs -https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#serverstatus.opcounters.command

This includes [many more commands](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#serverstatus.metrics.commands) than just `query` and `getmore`. Here is the full list from the mongodb docs, with commands excluded from the command count in **bold**.

- is_self
- aggregate
- build_info
- coll_stats
- connection_pool_stats
- count
- db_stats
- distinct
- find
- get_cmd_line_opts
- get_last_error
- get_log
- get_more
- get_parameter
- host_info
- **insert**
- is_master
- last_collections
- last_commands
- list_databased
- list_indexes
- ping
- profile
- replset_get_rbid
- replset_get_status
- replset_heartbeat
- replset_update_position
- server_status
- **update**
- whatsmyuri